# Sharepoint document library URL Rewrite

Tags: url, redirect, iis, sharepoint, url-rewriting

A Sharepoint library path has been changed from 'Shared%20Documents' to 'SharedDoc2024'
I tried to use the URL Rewrite to redirect all traffic to the new path.

**Pattern**: ^(.*)General-Accounting/Shared%20Documents/(.*)$
**Rewrite**: {R:1}General-Accounting/SharedDoc2024/{R:2}

The pattern test worked fine.  However, when I tested the address, no redirection happened.  it still went to 'Shared20%Ducments'.

```
<rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="FSC SharedDoc" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)General-Accounting\/Shared%20Documents\/(.*)$" />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}General-Accounting/SharedDocs2024/{R:2}"               redirectType="Found" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
```

[image]

Comment: You make a common mistake. Please read mistake 1 in  https://docs.lextudio.com/blog/the-very-common-mistakes-when-using-iis-url-rewrite-module-a2ab7e4fee59

Comment: Please enable FRT on your site and clear your browser cache, then retest the address to generate a tracking log. You can see the specific internal use of your rule through the log to determine where the problem occurs. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules